# How to Factor Out Polynomial Terms which Have Same Coefficient Differing Only by Sign

Tags: symbolic, polynomials, factorization

I'm new to the Mathematica StackExchange.

I am trying to simplify a polynomial in Mathematica.
In the following, I only show a part of the polynomial [image]

Here I want to combine terms with the same coefficients, up to sign difference. For example, I want to combine $H_1(H_2)^{\ast}$ and $H_2(H_1)^ {\ast}$ terms so that
[image]

My original attempt consisted of two steps. First, get a list of coefficients of the polynomial and deleting the duplicating terms differing only by a sign difference to obtain a unique list of coefficient as following:

`compareTerms[term1_, term2_] := term1 == term2 || term1 == -term2; DeleteDuplicates[CoeffPol, compareTerms].`

And I tried to factor out the polynomial by using `Collect` with the terms by the above coeffcient list:  `Collect[Polynomial, DeleteDuplicates[CoeffPol, compareTerms]`.

This approach was first successful, but became no longer successful for polynomial that have two coefficients with different sign, as shown in the picture above where the coefficients for $H_1(H_2)^{\ast}$ and $H_2(H_1)^ {\ast}$ have opposite signs. `Collect` function does not seem to recognize that the two coefficients are the same only differing by the sign. Is it possible to factor out  terms where the coefficients only differ by a sign? as in  [image]

I'd highly appreciate any hints! Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to include copy and pasteable code for your expressions rather than just their images.